# Select a campos de outra tabela com múltiplas chaves estrangeiras

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Eu tenho 4 tabelas :

```
Lojas(nomeLoja, *IDloja*, morada, telefone, email)

Bancos(nomeBanco, *IDbanco*, morada)

PlanoContas(*conta*, descricao)

Gestao(NIB, nConta, conta1, conta2, IDloja, IDbanco, *IDgestao*)
```

`conta1` e `conta2` são chaves estrangeiras de `PlanoContas`, `IDloja` chave estrangeira de `Lojas` e `IDbanco` chave estrangeira de `Bancos`.

Como consigo obter uma saída semelhante a esta:

```
IDgestao | NIB | nconta | nomeBanco | nomeLoja | descricao_conta1 | descricao_conta2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basta fazer um `join` normal, dando nomes (*aliases*) para as tabelas consultadas e - no retorno do `select` - referenciando as tabelas específicas e também dando nomes para elas:

```
select g.IDgestao as IDgestao, g.NIB as NIB, g.nconta as nconta,
       b.nomeBanco as nomeBanco, l.nomeLoja as nomeLoja,
       c1.descricao as descricao_conta1, c2.descricao as descricao_conta2
from Gestao as g
     join Lojas as l on g.IDloja = l.IDloja
     join Bancos as b on g.IDbanco = b.IDbanco
     join PlanoContas as c1 on g.conta1 = c1.conta
     join PlanoContas as c2 on g.conta2 = c2.conta
where ...
```

Nota: o `as` na seção `from` é opcional; você poderia simplesmente usar `Gestao g`, `Lojas l` etc. Não tenho certeza quanto ao uso no `select`, mas me parece ser obrigatório nesse caso.

Comment: IDloja e IDbancos não são chaves primarias na tabela Gestão, são apenas na tabela Bancos e Lojas, respectivamente... Nunca tinha feito tantos joins simultaneamente... dái não visualizar à primeira... Mais uma vez obrigado!

Comment: @user8539 Ah tá, me passou despercebido que o mesmo nome de coluna existia nas duas tabelas... Removi o comentário.

Comment: @mgibsonbr a palavra `as` não seria necessária no `SELECT` ao menos que quer dar um nome diferente ao coluna. Por exemplo, `SELECT g.IDgestao AS Digestion`. Por padrão, o Sql Server usa o nome da coluna. Também algumas colunas pode ter o `AS` enquanto outros podem ficar sem.